# Using Acceleo 3 with Ant

Tags: java, generated-code, acceleo

I'm looking for information on how to perform Acceleo source generation with an Ant script. I've done some Googleing, but I haven't really found any straightforward way to do that. I'm looking first to do it in Eclipse, but a headless (is that the right word?) script would also be nice for semi-automatic builds.

Can anyone offer any help? Or are my expectations of what Acceleo can do unreasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is to use a  ant task to call your generation class.
The generation class is the one generated along your mtl file that contains an "@main" annotation.

Beware though, the generation will run in standalone mode, so don't use services that rely on eclipse API!

The ant task should look like this:

```
<java classname="your.generation.class.GenerateJava"
        classpathref="your.classpath.defined.in.ant">
    <arg value="your/input/model/example.uml"/>
    <arg value="your/target/folder" />
</java>
```

Hope this will help...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. We're using an ecore model, does that change anything? Sorry for the noob questions, but I'm new to this kind of source generation.

Comment: Using an Ecore model won't make any difference, it should be straightforward.